# Detect the sign in number input

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

how can i detect if the input number in textbox contains "-"
so i can change the output into positive number and
if not contain "-" the output number is become negative
i'm using Vb.net 2010 tnx in advance for who wants to help

Comment: Check if the first character of the input is "-"

Comment: how can i do that exactly or should i say how can i check it.

Comment: Try reading up the documentation on `String` class maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim output As String   
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
If getbyte(TextBox1.Text, 0) = Chr(45) Then ' check whether the first character is - or not 
output = New String((From c As Char In TextBox1.Text Select c Where Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray())
else
output="-" & textbox1.text
End If
msgbox (CInt(output))' will give the  number
End Sub
```

Getbyte function to take each character from a string based on the position

```
Private Function getbyte(ByVal s As String, ByVal place As Integer) As String
    If place < Len(s) Then
    place = place + 1
    getbyte = Mid(s, place, 1)
    Else
    getbyte = ""
    End If
End Function
```

if you want to convert the -eve number to positive for calculation you can use

Comment: on the 2nd code that you post. . how does that exactly work ?

Comment: this function is used to find the character at particular position, it will take input string, position as input and returns the character @ the position referred in the input. here input is "-1523" and position is 0 then the output will be "-"

Comment: when i input "-2" it gave me an output positive "2" which is correct but when i try to input positive "2" it gave me an output positive "2" which is wrong. . when user input positive number like"2" the output should become negative "-2" and use it in the computation. .

Comment: can you show me the expected input and out put? for bot +eve and -eve inputs?

Comment: sample if user input a negative number "-2" or any number including as long it is negative. . it will turn to positive "2". and the output will use in computation. .  if user input a positive number "3" or any number as long it is positive. . . it will turn to negative "-3" and the output will use in computation. . .  any number, fraction, or decimal numbers  is expected in input and output. .

Comment: see updates,, if more updates needed  come to chat through above link

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of options, two of them are:

1) Use `StartsWith` functions:

```
If Textbox1.Text.Trim().StartsWith("-"))Then
  ' It is a negative number
End If
```

2) If you just need to toggle the number sign, then:

```
Dim number as Integer = Integer.Parse(Textbox1.Text) ' Preferrably use Integer.TryParse()
number *= -1    ' Toggle the number sign
```

Using option2, i get:

```
    Dim txta1 As New TextBox
    txta1.Text = "-2"

    Dim number As Double = Double.Parse(txta1.Text) ' Preferrably use Integer.TryParse() 
    number *= -1 ' Toggle the number sign 
    Dim s As String = number & " | "
```

Output: `2 |`

Comment: How would you like to use it ? It is a number so yes you can, if you have to support decimal precision as well, you can use `Decimal` or `Single` or `Double` instead of `Integer` based on your need.

Comment: there is a problem. . i input "-2" using your code and it gives me a "-1" output. . which must be if i input "-2" the output must be positive "2" and the positive "2" which will be use in computation

Comment: How it is possible that multiplying an number with `-1` changes value instead of sign ? Can you show us your findings pleas ?

Comment: Dim number As Double = Double.Parse(txta1.Text) ' Preferrably use Integer.TryParse()
        number *= -1    ' Toggle the number sign
        CRCF_Computation1.lblout9.Text = number & "  | "

Comment: the "-2" is sample input only of a user. . .  user can input any number, fraction, and decimal. . (positive or negative)